# How to make augmented reality without tracker

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I wants to develop AR application which show 3D object in it's original size by moving the camera left , right , up & down .

Suppose I have a 3D building Object . If I'm making AR application of this building object using [Vuforia  SDK for unity](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/getting-started-unity-extension) , it seem's that I need to use a tracker object, I am using Image-Targets the limitation i'm getting here is the tracker can't show the building in it'd original size , I mean the tracker only showing the building when i'm re-sizing the building which will fit on tracker image properly .

Please guide me how will I meet my requirement to show the Original size of object in 3D world by moving the camera left, right , top & down such as accelerometer sensor.
If someone have problem to understand my need please revert me .

Regards
anupam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not strictly a programming question, however I will try to help.
I suppose you want to work with a real scale building.

First, there is no limitation on Vuforia on showing objects on real scale, the limitation is that the marker should be visible and to see a big building you will need a very big marker so you could be far enough and still see the virtual components in real scale.

If you want to stick with Vuforia, your best options are:

- Use the extended tracking capability: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/extended-tracking.
- Use the smart terrain feature, although it will not fit your needs as I think you want to track a real scale building (not sure because you didn´t provide enough information regarding your scenario).
- This a more custom solution, detect the marker for the first time and based on that information anchor the 3D object to that position and stop tracking the marker, then you will rely only on the device sensors like the accelerometer to interact and explore the object.

Now, as you said "without a marker", Vuforia still does not support 3D tracking oficially, so if you want to track a real scale building, Vuforia could not be the best option, instead I recommend more suitable options (depending what you need and what you want to achieve):

1. Metaio 3D tracking capabilities powered by SLAM.
2. Use geolocation (GPS) to explore the real world object without a marker.
3. You custom solution using SLAM.

Lastly, there are very different ways to tackle this problem, I will recommend you to read computer vision and AR literature to have the whole picture, I am only listing the ideas that came to my mind at the time of writing this answer.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, I've just looking for how to implement "detect the marker for the first time and based on that information anchor the 3D object to that position and stop tracking the marker" if you have related articles books, will appreciate